# Do we really need [latex] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

We have 15 questions tagged [latex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex), several already closed and few others being, in my opinion, candidates to being closed. This tag and most of the questions are off-topic. Maybe we should delete the bluntly off-topic questions and re-tag the rest to get rid of the questions? Notice that to delete the questions we would need to cast multiple votes (I already casted mine) or moderator intervention would be needed.

Comment: I think you are right, this tag is not needed and many questions seem to be off-topic. It would be good if you could vote to close the ones that you think are off-topic. And start retagging all of them, unless somebody protests here soon.

Comment: I already did. The one problem I just noticed is that there are about four or five questions with many upvotes and answers that actually ask about using latex...

Comment: Regarding deletion, I am not sure how it works. Take e.g. this Q: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48311. It's closed as off-topic 4 years ago but has 2 upvotes and 2 answers with 2 and 3 upvotes. It won't get automatically deleted until all posts there have 0 votes or less. However, I see that you (?) voted to delete it and I have now voted too just to see what will happen, so there is currently 2 votes for deleting it. I am not sure what our policy is in situations like that. Should we vote to delete such threads? I never thought about this before.

Comment: There are *lots* of older threads here with a lot of upvotes, answers, and views, that by now are closed as off-topic. The on-topic policy used to be less strict some years ago.

Comment: Threads that seem to be acceptable at the time can be grandfathered in (so left open if deemed of historical value, such as the "jokes" thread which is absolutely off topic now). If the vote to close was around the time of the post (and not a year later, say), and the historical/interest value of the thread is not obvious (nb lots of upvotes would suggest some value in that sense), while closing would allow us to clean up or streamline something else, we should probably lean toward closing. However, closing many now-off-topic threads might be quite disruptive in several ways.

Comment: @amoeba, I just voted to delete that one, & it seems to be gone now.

Comment: Do these predate the [TeX.SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Hey Tim, are you planning to remove [latex] from the remaining questions?

Comment: @amoeba Glen_b has made a good point about deleting threads and it is still not clear for me what should we do with the non-obvious cases.

Comment: I feel that the tag should be removed even if some questions are on-topic or grandfathered or whatever. The same goes for the [sweave] tag, by the way.

Comment: @Glen_b do you have any additional comments?

Comment: @Tim If you're not sure whether to close or not and it's fairly old, I'd just leave it. If you're pretty sure that none of the reasons to keep it have much force in a particular case, then vote to delete. If you make a mistake either way it's probably not a big deal in this case (old threads now clearly off topic)

Comment: Looking at the voting in the comments under my answer, I think we can go ahead and remove latex+sweave tags.

Comment: So I went ahead and removed both tags. Case closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some questions were closed & got deleted, and the current situation is as follows. There are 7 questions left in [latex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex), 5 of which are closed as off-topic. The 2 remaining ones are arguably on-topic and are about [project-management](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management).

There is a closely related [sweave](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweave) tag. Together, [latex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) and [sweave](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweave) have 10 threads, with 6 closed and 4 remaining open in [project-management](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management).

I have edited tag wiki excerpts for both tags to warn about possible off-topic-ness:

> A typesetting system often used for scientific documents. Questions about LaTeX are off-topic unless they have statistical content.

and

> A tool that allows to embed R code into LaTeX documents to create dynamic reports. Questions about Sweave are off-topic unless they have statistical content.

---

I don't have a strong opinion on whether we should now eliminate these tags or let them be.

**Please vote in the comments and/or comment to provide arguments.**

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think these two tags should be deleted.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you think these two tags should stay.

Comment: Upvote this comment if you don't really care either way.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Based on the voting results (currently 3 votes for deleting, 1 for keeping, and 2 don't care votes), I have just now deleted both tags.